# Can I mix inferred and exlicit generic type parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Assum I have this extension function:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified R> Any.getPrivateProperty(variableName: String): R { … }
```

I can quite conveniently call this with something like `s.getPrivateProperty<Int>("height")`, an expression that is of type `Int`.

Now I wanted to make sure the function is only defined on non-optional types. I used the definitely-not-nullable notation:

```kotlin
inline fun <T: Any, reified R> T.getPrivateProperty(variableName: String): R { … }
```

This fulfills the purpose, however, since I have that one type parameter which must be explicit, I actually have to give both now. Example: `s.getPrivateProperty<Shape, Int>("height")`.

Is it even possible to avoid that *in general*? Is there an alternative way to avoid that *here*, that is, to only define the extension function over non-optional types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of the function *already* does not work on nullable types. For example, this doesn't compile.

```
val x: String? = "foo"
val y = x.getPrivateProperty<String>("foo")
```

Before Kotlin 1.7, when calling a function, you must specify all the type parameters in the `<...>` part, or you must let all of them be inferred.

There *are* ways to infer `R` in this case though. It needs not be always written in `<>`. Simply do:

```
val y: String = x.getPrivateProperty("foo")
//     ^^^^^^
```

That is, since `R` is the return type, you can just write it as the type of the variable you are assigning to.

For non-return types, if for some reason Kotlin can't infer them, a simple way to "infer" them is to pass a `Dummy<T>`, to let the caller specify.

```
class Dummy<T>

// imagine foo having some other parameters using T and U, 
// but T can't be inferred for whatever reason, but U can be inferred
// you can just add an extra parameter of type Dummy<T>
fun <T, U> foo(... other parameters ..., t: Dummy<T>) { ... }
```

Then the caller can do:

```
foo(..., Dummy<SomeType>())
```

without having to specify `U` as well.

For non-nullable type parameters, you can use `KClass<T>` instead of creating your own `Dummy<T>`.

Comment: _“The first version of the function already does not work on nullable types”_ – you are right, of course. I must have take a wrong turn somewhere while fiddling around. Thank you for the nice extended explanation, though!

Comment: “you must specify all the type parameters in the <...> part, or you must let all of them be inferred.” — that was true for a long time, but [Kotlin 1.7.0 introduced](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments) an [underscore operator for type arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments) which lets you specify some while letting others be inferred.

Comment: @gidds Oh wow. I'm using Kotlin 1.9 already and did not know that until now.

Comment: (Whoops, I didn't mean to post that comment, as I decided it was worth making into an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In earlier versions of Kotlin, it wasn't possible to mix inferred and specified type arguments; but [Kotlin 1.7.0 introduced](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments) an [underscore operator for type arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments) which lets you do that.

The underscore indicates an unspecified type, in a similar way to how it does in lists of function formal parameters or destructuring declarations.

So in this case, you could use:

```
s.getPrivateProperty<_, Int>("height")
```

instead of:

```
s.getPrivateProperty<Shape, Int>("height")
```

(As Sweeper's answer explains, the `fun Any.getPrivateProperty(…)` is already defined only for a non-nullable receiver, so you may not need it here anyway.)

Comment: A shame I can’t set two accept hooks…

Comment: @MichaelPiefel No problem — Sweeper's answer are always good, so I won't blame him for nicking my idea :-)